How to create the cartesian product of a list of lists of tuples
I'm trying to accomplish a cartesian product of a list of lists. The base elements are tuples. Something about the tuples seems to really throw product off. The more products I attempt the more it adds a rat's nesting of tuples.
Here's my code
from itertools import product

listOfListsOfTuples = [ [(1,2),], [(3,4),(5,6)] ]
got = list(product(*listOfListsOfTuples))
print('got   :',got)

wanted = [ [(1,2),(3,4)], [(1,2),(5,6)] ]
print('wanted:',wanted)

and my output
got   : [((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (5, 6))]
wanted: [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (5, 6)]]

Maybe I need to fall back to for loops and do it myself?
EDIT: was made aware I need a * on the call to product, so added that. That changed my output, so I changed that to my new output above.  Note that got != wanted

product takes iterables as a separate arguments, not as a single iterable of iterables. So, just missing a star to expand listOfListsOfTuples:
product(*listOfListsOfTuples)

Straight from the docs

itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)


Cartesian product of input iterables.

UPD: product will always yield tuples. To get lists, you'll need to explicitly convert:
got = [list(tuples) for tuples in product(*listOfListsOfTuples))]


This got me 95% of the way there.  Please see my edits to the question.

If I change my input to a list-of-tuples-of-tuples, I get the same got output - a list-of-tuples-of-tuples.  Then if I change my wanted list-of-lists-of-tuples to a list-of-tuples-of-tuples, too, then got == wanted.  I think this may work.  I'll have to go plug it into my real program and work it through several rounds of products to verify.

@CAB updated the answer.
